# Xaml MergedDictionaries cant find eachothers resources

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, dictionary

I have a problem with two dictionaries:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles1.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles2.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

When I set one resource in the first dictionary, for example a Color.
Then it wont find it in the second dictionary????

First:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Color x:Key="ApplicationPageBackgroundColor">#FFFFFFFF</Color>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ApplicationPageBackgroundColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundColor}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Second: ( Setter Property="Background" Value ....    generates error)

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="LayoutRootStyle" TargetType="Panel">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundColorBrush}" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

If I put them in the same dictionary it works, any suggestions?

Comment: So you're trying to loop your references with circular dependencies?

Comment: Not circular, but one way dependant

Answer (score 0):

`Styles2.xaml` has no reference to `Styles1.xaml` and vice versa. For StaticResource to work the dictionary entry must be statically visible at the point of use ("in scope"). In the same way you can't refer to a resource defined later in the same XAML file.

In WPF a DynamicResource might do what you want, but that's not available in WinRT. You would have to merge the 1st resource into the 2nd (and not have any circular dependency), or place the shared part somewhere visible to both (eg `Application.Resources`).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. All I want is to split my huge resource dictionary in multiple dictionaries, start by splitting my used collor pallets from the controls. So the collors dictionary must me reachable for all other dictionaries, and not backwards. I would prefer to leave the app.xaml as empty.

Comment: Any suggestions how to share 1 dictionary to all other?

Comment: You can merge it in all explicitly as merged dictionary, though depending how big/often that could have some performance impact. For common colours etc this seems like a good bet to me. Or if it's really used everywhere put it in app.xaml, that's kind of what it's for.

Comment: So if I understand correct, there is no way that a value can be shared from one dictionary to one other? I Would love to make one of my collection of dictionaries shared, but I don't know how or even if this is possible.